# count duplicates in sql for 1 column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

how i can fill out "category" in table 1 in the case where there are multiple in table 2? I would like to fill as multiple if there are multiple categories per object.

[image]

attempt:

```
select t1.*,
case case when count(t2.category)>1 then 'Multiple' else cast(t2,category as varchar)
from table1 t1
left join table 2 t2 on t2.object=t1.object
```

Issue, its asking for group by, i have over 80 columns, is there anyway to bypass group by?

Answer (score 0):

Create an expression for the value using a subquery:

```
select
  t1.*,
  case (select count(*) from table2 t2 where t2.object = t1.object)
    when 0 then 'None'
    when 1 then (select cast(max(t2,category) as varchar)) from table2 t2 where t2.object = t1.object)
    else 'Multiple'
  end as category
from table1 t1
```

This avoids listing all columns in either the group by clause in the case of aggregation approach, or the select clause in the case of using a query over a subquery.

I added `None` as a result because you used a `left join`, indicating that joining rows are optional.

This wouldn't perform well with large numbers of rows, but should be fine with modest table sizes.

Comment: Hi, everything is coming back as multiple. i tried flipping the tables up in the "from"  as well; same result. I also tested another column from table 2 which doesnt need to be converted to varchar. Example: select t1.*, 
case (select count(*) from table2 as t2 left join table1 as t1 on t1.category=t2.category)
when 0 then 'None'
when 1 then (select max(t2.category) from table2 as t2 left join table1 as t1 on t2.category = t1.category)
else 'Multiple' end as category
from table1 as t1

Comment: Create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with sample data and post the link here and I’ll get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
select
distinct
t1.*,
case when c.object is not null then 'Multiple' else b.category end as category
from
table1 t1
left outer join 
table2 t2
on t1.object = t2.object
left outer join
(select object from table2 group by object having count(*) > 1) c
on t1.object = c.object
```